# How to construe terms of a license agreement?

Tags: licensing, legal-terms

I read a license agreement and it seems the following part is vague:

> Without prejudice to any statutory rights so to do, you must not reproduce or alter any of the software or any associated documentation.

1) Does "*Without prejudice to any statutory rights so to do*" mean "*If your local law supports this limitation*"?

2) Does "*you must not*" means that "*you are not allowed*"?

3) Does "*any of the software or any associated documentation*" mean "*either the software or any associated documentation*"? Or does it mean "*any part of the software or its associated documentation*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation:

> Except where the law allows you to, you cannot reproduce any part of the software or the documentation.

"Must not" is an imperative: you are prohibited.

Statutory rights would be rights under the applicable law, the jurisdiction where the licence is granted certainly and possibly others.

Comment: Does *must not* mean *may not* or *are not allowed to* and doing so infringes the contract?

Comment: And *statutory rights* may vary from country to counnty or state to state. Does *any statutory rights* mean *local law of where the software is bought or used*

Comment: By "where the licence is granted" do you mean where the software is bought and used?